# How to create managers for the worker threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, pool

The code works fine for a single "manager", which basically launches some HTTP GETs to a server.  But I've hit a brick wall.

How do I create 2 managers now, each with its own Download_Dashlet_Job object and tcp_pool_object?  In essence, the managers would be commanding their own workers on two seperate jobs.  This seems to be a really good puzzle for learning Python classes.

```
import workerpool
from urllib3 import HTTPConnectionPool

class Download_Dashlet_Job(workerpool.Job):
  def __init__(self, url):
    self.url = url
  def run(self):
    request = tcp_pool_object.request('GET', self.url, headers=headers)

tcp_pool_object = HTTPConnectionPool('M_Server', port=8080, timeout=None, maxsize=3, block=True)
dashlet_thread_worker_pool_object = workerpool.WorkerPool(size=100)

#this section emulates a single manager calling 6 threads from the pool but limited to 3 TCP sockets by tcp_pool_object
for url in open("overview_urls.txt"):
  job_object = Download_Dashlet_Job(url.strip())
  dashlet_thread_worker_pool_object.put(job_object)

dashlet_thread_worker_pool_object.shutdown()
dashlet_thread_worker_pool_object.wait()
```

Comment: I looked into Celery...it's very interesting.  I see it has a lot of potential there, but probably overkill for what I'm doing.  I'm just basically writing a load test for a server (ie, does said server support 200+ clients all at once).

Answer (score 0):

First, `workerpool.WorkerPool(size=100)` creates 100 worker threads. In the comment below, you're saying you want 6 threads? You need to change that to 6.

In order to create a second pool, you need to create another pool. You can also create another job class, and just add this different type of job to the same pool, if you prefer.